# Consider special characters in search of value in MongoDB Compass using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I have a record with some values as below:

[{name: "fdyc+23",size: "s",cost: "250},{name: "1++LION",size: "NA", cost: "180"},{name: "fd_smst",        size: "s",cost: "230"},{name: "1-NAKH---",size: "s",cost: "250"},{name: "round .1 mg",size: "s",cost: "250"}]

I want to make search on all the fields. I have tried below code snnipet:

```
    var result = await db.collection.find({
        $or: [{ name: { $regex: <searchInput>, $options: "i" } },
        { size: { $regex: <searchInput>, $options: "i" } },
        { cost: { $regex: <searchInput>, $options: "i" } }]
    });
```

I want to make it work for all special characters or any sort of input value provided in the request params.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I would use my own defiend regular expression to escape any special characters, I modified your code as below, let's see if it works on your end.

```
const escapeRegExp = (input) => {
  return input.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
};

const searchInput = req.query.searchInput;
const escapedSearchInput = escapeRegExp(searchInput);

var result = await db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    { name: { $regex: escapedSearchInput, $options: "i" } },
    { size: { $regex: escapedSearchInput, $options: "i" } },
    { cost: { $regex: escapedSearchInput, $options: "i" } }
  ]
});
```